# I am getting a "Not a directory" error mounting a drive using ansible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible, devops, mount

I am trying to mount a drive using ansible. Here is my playbook

```
- name: Create directory
  file:
    path: /u01
    state: directory

- name: Create a filesystem on a drive
  filesystem:
    fstype: xfs
    dev: /dev/xvdf

- name: Mount the drive and update the fstab file
  mount:
    backup: yes
    path: /u01
    src: /dev/xvdf
    opts: bind
    state: mounted
    fstype: xfs
```

When I run it, the first 2 ntasks get completed. A directory is created and a filesystem is also created. However, I get the following error when I get to the final step:

```
TASK [mount : Mount the drive and update the fstab file] ****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.31.42.187]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error mounting /u01: mount: /u01: mount(2) system call failed: Not a directory.\n"}
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this?

Comment: It means there is a file at `/u01`

Comment: @stark how can there be a file there when I've just created the directory on the first part of the play book? What do I need to do?

Comment: What happens when your try to mount the drive directly on the host ? Are you running those commands as root ? Did you check the directory directly on the target host and its permissions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. I thnk the main issue was with the opts parameter, I changed it to defaults,nofail and it worked. So the playbook now looks like this:

```
- name: Create a filesystem on a drive
  filesystem:
    fstype: xfs
    dev: /dev/xvdb

- name: Mount the drive and update the fstab file
  mount:
    backup: yes
    path: "/u01"
    src: /dev/xvdb
    opts: defaults,nofail
    state: mounted
    fstype: xfs
```